# How to find out why compiled GWT app doesn't initialize but works in hosted mode?

Tags: java, gwt

How to find out why compiled GWT app doesn't initialize but works in hosted mode ?

In production it doesn't even show initial view. No exceptions (there are none in JavaScript I guess), no errors. Just empty webpage.

I'm using Chrome.

Comment: In FF, you can use Firebug extension to see a little bit more what is happening. Are your script files found (look in the Net tab)? Are there any JS error (look in the Console tab)?

Comment: Probably your Browser doesnt support loading local files in another directory as they are treated like they would be from another server. Easiest way to solve this is to upload the whole directory to your server or you public dropbox folder. You could also start Chrome with --disable-web-security

Comment: are we talking about an app that has been deployed before? i.e. so you can rule out problem with compilation, packaging, uploading, etc.

Comment: The similar happened to me once when no javascript errors were given in production, however in dev mode it worked just fine. In my case it was caused by some improper DOM manipulation. We have too few information to guess. I would suggest devide it by smaller parts and test one-by-one, gradually turning off various part and such way localize the issue.

Comment: I have the same behaviour - check your start page. `<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="module_name/module_name.nocache.js"></script>` **module_name** has to be the same like in your `*.gwt.xml`

Comment: Have you activated the Chrome Developer Tools? CTRL+SHIFT+I on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of errors in the console and no visible activity on the page it usually means that the page is not set-up correctly so:

- Make sure your host page is set up correctly as per the
  [documentation](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideHostPage).
- Make sure you are using [standards mode](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels.html#Standards) and
  your page declares the HTML5 doctype `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Post more code/information if you would like a further discussion.

Comment: You know I noticed that sometimes GWT compiler simply doesn't produce .nocache.js file. I don't see any errors in log either.

Answer (score -1):

The strange part about this issue is that it does work, but with any other browser, including IE!? And not Chrome?!

What I did was to follow step by step the GWT tutorial to create an app (StockWatcher)
In development mode it worked flawlessly in Chrome, but after I compiled the project, the result was no longer working inside Chrome, though the rest of the browsers worked!

So, try to see if the production version works inside other browsers.